# pkgconfig option for gtk-2.0

Tags: pkg-config

GCC is returning the following error

```
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32:21: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory
```

Using `find /usr -name 'gdk.h'` I was able to locate the missing header in

```
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h
```

I'm guessing the error is arising form the fact that the compiler isn't looking in `gtk-2.0` for the `gdk` directory, though I could be mistaken about that. If I am correct, what is the `pkgconfig` option for `gtk-2.0`, and if I'm wrong, what is it I'm really doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs
pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags
```

the first gives the option to link the libs, the second the paths; I usually use something like

```
gcc $(pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags) $(pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs) project.c -o project
```

of course when I want to compile "on the fly". Otherwise, you should use a semiautomatic way of doing this (configure script, Makefiles and so on)

Answer (score 1):

For me (on Debian) it was a different problem:

> checking GTK_CFLAGS... Package libpng12 was not found in the
>   pkg-config search path.  Perhaps you should add the directory
>   containing `libpng12.pc'  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable 
>   Package 'libpng12', required by 'GdkPixbuf', not found

Then I remembered this X11-startup-fail problem I was having the week before, right after upgrading libpng to latest experimental - which I had fixed by manually restoring previous version's .so files.. I forgot the pkgconfig files though. So this build problem fixed by properly "downgrading libpng12-0:i386 from 1.5.11-1 to 1.2.49-1."
Bottom line: look at the configure output **above** the actual error. And don't install experimental libpng, chances are high it'll *brick* your GUI completly ;)

Answer (score 0):

The trick `$(pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags) $(pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs)` solved my problem.
I wonder why gtk/gtk.h had  is not in the  gtk dir. kind of redirection confusions.